# How to disable BlueZ cache?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

In "/etc/bluetooth/main.conf", there seems a way to disable the cache:

```
[GATT]
Cache = no
```

What does exactly the "disable cache" mean? It means the "/var/lib/bluetooth/[MAC_ADDRESS]/cache" folder won't be created?

We tried to disable the cache by changing the "/etc/bluetooth/main.conf". It seems the "/var/lib/bluetooth/[MAC_ADDRESS]/cache" folder is still created even if it was deleted.
However, we noticed that the "[Attributes]" section in "/var/lib/bluetooth/[MAC_ADDRESS]/cache/[iPHONE_MAC]" file is gone. Does it mean the "disable cache" is working? Does it mean the handles used between the bluetooth and the mobile app won't be cached?

Thanks!